# Android Bluetooth socket closed: read return: -1

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I am trying out the [Bluetooth Guide from google on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#kotlin).

And when trying to connect to another device, the connection succeeds but immediately after, when I start listening to incoming bytes, I get this exception: `socket closed: read return: -1`

Here is the code for the connection, copied from the google guide.

```
private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread() {

private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
}

public override fun run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
    mBluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

    mmSocket?.use { socket ->
        // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
        socket.connect()

        // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
        // the connection in a separate thread.
        manageMyConnectedSocket(socket)
    }
}

// Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
fun cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket?.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the code posted on the google guide.

The issue is that they call `mmSocket?.use {}` then proceed to connect using this socket. The `use()` method is a really useful extension function for `Disposable` objects to perform actions on them and then call `close()` on them at the end of the action.

In this case it is clearly a bug. You do not want to close the socket immediately after having made the connection.

To make it work, just replace the `mmSocket?.use {}` by `mmSocket?.let {}` and you will be good to go.

Hopefully google will update their guide.

Comment: `use` is a correct method to call for a socket actually. You're connecting, using the socket and when you're done with it it's closed automatically.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I absolutely agree that it would be correct in many cases. But here, at the end of the block, you pass the socket to another thread and the block closes the socket before you can do anything with it.